# My LiveCode stack size is too large for my display. Is there away to adjust it so that it fits on my screen?

Tags: livecode

When working with a large LiveCode stack (e.g. 2048 x 1536), the stack take up more screen space than is available (monitor resolution is 1368 x 768).

I can somewhat work around this by programatically positioning the stack.g.

```
set the loc of this stack to 1000,500
```

but this is pretty time consuming and awkward.

Is there any solutions to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the latest stable release, 6.6.1, there is a scaleFactor property that you can use to scale the visual size of the stack to a percentage of its actual size.

```
set the scaleFactor of stack "hugeStack" to .75
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
set the fullscreenmode of this stack to “exactFit”
```

on the stack? That should activate the new scaling stuff that was added in 6.5.

(See here: http://livecode.com/livecode-6-5/)

Answer (score 0):

See this post [download shuffleAbout](http://forums.runrev.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=12712&hilit=Chipp%20Walters&sid=445b836b79ea59514510a33d6ac4979d#p60592) and download the stack that you can use as plugin.